# Why default Centos installation has partitions?

Tags: centos, partition

I installed Centos 6.3 and looking at the disk I get the output:

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg_cp77-lv_root
                       50G  7.3G   40G  16% /
tmpfs                 1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1             485M   63M  397M  14% /boot
/dev/mapper/vg_cp77-lv_home
                      144G  188M  136G   1% /home
```

I did not partition my disk so how is this happening, I have been using Ubuntu and never experienced such a problem before?

Comment: What would you prefer? Just `/` and `/boot`?

Answer (score 5):

Because these are the defaults that the CentOS maintainers have decided to go with. I believe that these are inherited from a default RHEL install. You were given a choice to review these options and to change them, so I'm not sure what your actual problem is.